# How to solve the consumer error in Rabbitmq using python

Tags: rabbitmq

when I run Consumer.py for headersExchange in rabbitmq using python,it is getting error like below
I have mentioned consumer and publish program below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "headersConsumer.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "headersConsumer.py", line 14, in main
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange = 'headers_logs',exchange_type='headers',durable=True)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2387, in 
exchange_declare
    self._flush_output(declare_ok_result.is_ready)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1339, in 
_flush_output
    raise self._closing_reason  # pylint: disable=E0702
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (406, "PRECONDITION_FAILED 
- inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'headers_logs' in vhost '/': received 'headers' but 
current is 'fanout'")
```

I have written consumer code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika, sys, os

def main():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()    

    channel.exchange_declare(exchange = 'headers_logs',exchange_type='headers',durable=True)

    channel.queue_declare(queue = "HeaderQueue1", durable=True)

    channel.queue_bind(exchange = 'headers_logs', queue="HeadersQueue1", routing_key='',  
arguments={'x-match': 'any', 'key1': 'one', 'key2': 'two'})

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] %r" % body.decode())

    print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.basic_consume(
        queue="HeadersQueue1", on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

I have written publish program likethis

```
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='headers_logs',exchange_type='headers')

message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or "Hello World!"
channel.basic_publish((exchange='headers_logs',routing_key="",body=message,properties=pika.BasicProperties(
        delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
        headers = {'key1':'one', 'key2': 'three'}
    ))

print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

I am not understanding this error,Can anyone please suggest this error

Answer (score 1):

`PRECONDITION_FAILED` means that you declared an exchange with set of parameters then you are trying to create the same queue name using different parameters.

in your case:

```
headers_logs' in vhost '/': received 'headers' but 
current is 'fanout'")
```

so you are trying to change the exchange type from fanout to headers

Se [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#property-equivalence) for more detail (this is for the queues but exchanges work in the same way).

> Before a queue can be used it has to be declared. Declaring a queue
> will cause it to be created if it does not already exist. The
> declaration will have no effect if the queue does already exist and
> its attributes are the same as those in the declaration. When the
> existing queue attributes are not the same as those in the declaration
> a channel-level exception with code 406 (PRECONDITION_FAILED) will be
> raised.